# Java regex split

Tags: java, regex

I'm new to regex.

I have a string `&#50;&#175;&#60;` .

I want to get the '&#number' part.

I tried with the following pattern:

`Pattern.compile("\\&#([0-9]+);/")`

but no result.

Comment: There are 3 &#number parts.  Which do you want?

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `/` at the end. Also, you don't need to escape the `&`; that character doesn't have any special meaning there. So, just:

```
Pattern.compile("&#([0-9]+);");
```

Answer (score 1):

For completeness using ruakh's regex:

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("&#([0-9]+);");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    while(m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group());
    }
```